# Ubuntu unable to find AWS CLI when installed via pip3

Tags: python-3.x, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to install AWS CLI using `pip3` as follows:

```
user@machine:~/Personal/aws-tutorial$ pip3 install awscli
```

Once installed, I am trying to check the version

```
aws --version
-bash: /usr/bin/aws: No such file or directory
```

Which fails mentioning that `aws` could not be found.

Could someone please help me resolve this?

I am currently on Ubuntu 20.04 running Python 3.8.10.

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

Comment: maybe `$HOME/.local/bin` not in `$PATH`

Comment: @ufopilot It is indeed in the path. What's happening is that the shell is trying to look at the path `/user/bin/aws` and I don't know why.

Comment: @AnSOUser search for aws in $HOME `find ~/ -type f -name aws`

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: check you PATH env, add awscli dir into PATH.

I tested your step

```bash
# root user
root@26be9a426bee: aws --version
aws-cli/1.24.10 Python/3.10.4 Linux/5.18.0-arch1-1 botocore/1.26.10
root@26be9a426bee: which aws
/usr/local/bin/aws
```

```bash
# normal user
eliot@laptop: which aws                                                                                                                                                                                        
/home/eliot/.local/bin/aws
```

Probably, you need check your PATH env by `echo $PATH`, and add aws dir into you PATH if they not in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

To install aws-cli package using pip,

```
$ python3 -m pip install awscli
```

It worked for me.